# How to do a specific type of join for two tables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76ced/2

I've got two tables - Roster and Sample. The Roster table contains information on what days an employee has worked across a period of two weeks. The Sample table contains a sample weekly roster.

I want to know how the days in Roster and Sample differ across each week of the Roster. Basically want something like the below table:

| Week | Roster Day | Sample Day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | Monday |
| 1 | Tuesday | Tuesday |
| 1 | Wednesday | Wednesday |
| 1 | Thursday | Thursday |
| 2 | Monday | Monday |
| 2 | Tuesday | Tuesday |
| 2 | Wednesday | Wednesday |
| 2 | Thursday | Thursday |
| 2 | Friday | NULL |

I've tried doing a simple outer join between the two tables but that did not give the desired result. It looks like I may need to do a cross join but I'm not sure how to incorporate that either. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to return rows from either side of the join when there is no matching row from the other row source, this requires a `full outer join` rather than just a standard `left outer join`.

Just doing the `full join` on it's own is not enough, as you still want to return a `null` for 'Monday' on week 1 even though there is a 'Monday' that would make the join. For this requirement you need to make sure both these columns are somehow involved in the `full join`. For this, you can `cross join` a `distinct` set of weeks and days to get a starting point.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/76ced/32

```
select coalesce(r.week, w.week) week, r.day roster_day, d.sample_day
from (select distinct week from roster) w
cross join (select [Day] sample_day from sample) d
full join roster r
  on  r.week = w.week
 and  r.day  = d.sample_day
order by 1
```

Note that the ordering is going to be pseudorandom without you adding something (so that 'Monday' is considered less than 'Friday'). You could do this be ordering by a `case when` expression against the day columns (something like `case when r.day = 'Monday' then 1 when r.day = 'Tuesday' then 2...` etc). It is a happy coincidence (although not completely unexpected given the access paths available and small data sets) that the SQL Fiddle returns results in the order you might want.